# Custom vee-validate input field

Tags: vuejs3, vee-validate

I have this input field here from vee-validate that is a simple password field. However currently i have a reveal password button that is outside of the field, I want to place the button inside the field and towards the end of the field, does anyone know how to do that?

```
<div class="form-group mb-3 ">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <Field name="password" :type="password.fieldType" class="form-control col-12"
        :class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.password }" id="password" :placeholder="t('password')" />
      <div class="d-flex px-2" @click="toggleVisibility">
        <div class="my-auto" v-if="password.fieldType === 'password'">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-eye-slash"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="my-auto" v-if="password.fieldType === 'text'">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ t('passwordIsRequired') }}</div>
  </div>
```

Desired output
[image: desired output]

Current output
[image: current output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Field component renders a simple input, if you need a more complex layout, you have to [use its default slot](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/field/#rendering-complex-fields-with-scoped-slots). Provide your own input along with any other elements, and bind the `field` slot prop to the input. The Field component will be renderless, except when you request a tag using the `as` prop.

Here is an example for Bootstrap 4.6:

```html
<Field 
  name="password"  
  placeholder="password"
  v-model="password.value"
  as="div"
  class="input-group form-group"
  v-slot="{field, errorMessage}"
>
  <input 
    v-bind="field" 
    :type="password.fieldType" 
    class="form-control col-12"
    :class="{ 'is-invalid': errorMessage }" 
  />
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" @click="toggleVisibility">
      <i 
        class="fa-solid" 
        :class="password.fieldType === 'text' ? 'fa-eye-slash' : 'fa-eye'"
      />
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ errorMessage }}</div>

</Field>
```

[playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)